# Mobile Foundation Migration Studio - Supported Eclipse versions

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2020/04/23/mobile-foundation-migration-studio-announce/

What is the supported version of eclipse to install this plug-in?   It says same as V7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported versions of Eclipse can be found at

https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CMobile%20OS%7CSolaris%7CWindows&duComponentIds=D005

Use this link to generate report above.